# Hypens Break Laravel Dynamic Routes

Tags: php, laravel

so I'm building a job board and have a route in my routes/web.php like this:

```
Route::get('/dublin-{slug}-jobs', [JobController::class, 'tag']);
```

If the slug is a single word like 'cleaning' jobs then the route works as expected however most of the slugs I have are two words connected with a hyphen like 'delivery-driver' so the URL /dublin-delivery-driver-jobs throws a 404 error.

My JobController:

```
public function tag($slug) {

    $jobs = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('published', 'true')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(90))->get();
    $tags = tag::where('live', 'true')->get();

    return view('home.tag')->with('jobs', $jobs)->with('tags', $tags);
}
```

Any insight into how to make this hypened route name work would be great

Comment: Use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to allow hyphens?

Comment: @sta added the controller code

Answer (score 2):

As @brombeer pointed out, using [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) fixed the issue, I added that to my route and it now works:

```
Route::get('/remote-{slug}-jobs', [JobController::class, 'tag'])->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+');
```